# Is it ok to throw away expired bag of food?

Tags: food

I just threw away an unopened 2 month old expired bag of pistachios.

I forgot that I had it and when I saw the date expired, I threw it in the trash bin.

Food should never be wasted, but is it ok to throw something expired away?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously one should strive as much as possible to always preserve food and make the best use of it. However, unexpected events could occur and food may get expired so the best use case in this scenario is to find a good way to discard the food; i.e., to find animals who could consume it safely. If that option is not available, then get rid of it and try next time to take best measures to not have surplus of food that will go to waste, and Allah knows best.